# Magento products won't show up

Tags: magento

Ok I followed everything this guy has mentioned in his article:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/311906/

The products are set as enabled, in stock, positive quantity, imported into my main shop.. nothing seems to be able to show up my products no matter what I do. It's not my theme either because I used one of the default themes that came with the Magento installation and it still won't display my products.

This is my shop front:

http://magento.neofill.com/magento/

Can anyone help me? :/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue, this worked for me:

http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination

Answer (score 1):

I think there are like 8 or 9 dependencies for a prdouct to show up. Having multiple storefronts will alter it.

Here is a list where to look for: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/

If you need more direction. Please let me know what kind of product it is (simple, bundle, etc.)